# Why can't I connect to an online MS Team Foundation project with C#

Tags: c#, tfs

I have looked at various examples, and there are few/none connecting to an online TFS account, connecting to a TFS project. Below is the last attempted code, that also didn't work. Yes, I am a neophyte to VS .Net (C#). Any direction is greatly appreciated:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client; 
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;

namespace TfsApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Uri collectionUri = new Uri("https://drmpractice.visualstudio.com");
            TfsTeamProjectCollection collection =
    new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
        collectionUri,
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@"myEmail@hotmail.com", "MyPassword"));
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = collection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

        }
    }
}
```

The returned error returned: "password, port, or project name is wrong".

Comment: When connecting with plain username and password, you need to setup alternate credentials in your profile. If you want to connect to VSO using an MSA, you'll need to let the Microsoft Account handle the signon process.

Comment: @jessehouwing I will try that ....

Comment: `drmpractice.visualstudio` is not the correct URL.  Try `drmpractice.visualstudio.com`.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yeah, that was a typo in the question. I am using drm ... com. Thanks.

Comment: @jessehouwing That worked ....